# My Android app is taking too much memory

Tags: android, android-activity, memory-leaks, heap-memory

**What I Have**

I have an app with some activities. Each activity has got some EditTexts, ImageViews, ImageButtons and have got access to SharedPreferences too.

**My Problem**

Whenever I move from one activity to the other, like from the splash screen to the login screen and then to the main activity, my heap size grows massively. It even reaches to 142 MB and my app crashes on many devices due to OutOfMemory error.

**What Have I Done Already**

I have already made all the references to null in the onPause() method and it reduces the heap size to some extent, but still it is around 80 MB all the time. I suspect the main problem is with the drawables as I have got that error too.

Please help me with some solution. What should I do to reduce the memory usage?

Comment: What are you doing with the drawables? Please show that code.

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party libs?

Comment: When it crashes, check where `OutOfMemory` error occurs and post that code here.

Comment: @VenomVendor Yes I am using two libraries, one is Zip4j and the other is SwipeListView.

Answer (score 2):

First of al, I highly recommend you to use MAT to profile the content of your heap.
http://android-developers.blogspot.be/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html

Be sure that you provide drawables in the adequat version and size (mdpi, hdpi, xhpdi...)

Answer (score 1):

IF you are sure that all your references are set to null at java side then their might be issue with the Drawables, i am posting a simple solution just put that code in your activity classes and then onDestroy call that code it will freeup all memory taken by drawables.

```
protected void unbindDrawables(View view) {
    if (view != null) {
        if (view.getBackground() != null) {
            view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
        }
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup && !(view instanceof AdapterView)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
            }
            ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
        }

    }

}
```

How to use this method.
View rootView;

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    rootView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.splashactivity,
            null);
    setContentView(rootView);
```

}

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();


    unbindDrawables(rootView);
    rootView = null;
    System.gc();

}
```

Comment: I have added your code to all my activities, but the heap size is still around 80 MB. Can you add a better way to release memory and reduce the heap size?

PS - I also have some fragments and ViewPager in one of my activity.

Comment: Did u call finish(); this will only work when ondestory is called and that only happena when u destroy activity. You can do that in onPause also but that would require u to setcontent view again onResume

Comment: Secondly use allocation tracker to view whats taking memory. 3rd put a log in unbinddrawablea method to see if it is being called or not and last set content view equals to an inflated layout not to use r.layout.yourlayout if this happens unbinddrawables wont work

Comment: I have called finish() when moving from one activity to te other using intents. Should I remove the fragments too in some way?

Comment: I am also using Shared Preferences, should I release it in some specisl way after use?

Comment: No it has nothing to do with shared prefs and yes u can unbind drawables in fragments also. Double check u have declared all unused things to null and are not using static objects  where not required